# Pycharm indent styling like rainbow indent extension in vs code

Tags: python, pycharm

I like working with **vs code** .. the theme and the **rainbow-indent extension** make it fun coding.

but Unfortunately, it doesn't work well with python code like Pycharm ..

so I use **Pycharm** when coding with python, that's why I'm trying to make it looks like vs code ..

I managed to make theme looks the same way but I can't achieve the rainbow-indent like this image :
https://ihatetomatoes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/img_indent-rainbow-default.png

is there a way to achieve that in Pycharm?

Comment: If there's a specific issue you have with the Python extension for VS Code then please open a feature request for what is missing at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Please install my plugin [Indent Rainbow](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13308-indent-rainbow)

It does exactly what you want:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks, it's really awesome :)